# What is the best script language for n/w programming + web development

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I'm interested in developing web application and networking application. For that what
 is the best script language to learn. Which one is effective for this two. So for, i don't 
know even a single syntax of any scripting language. Which is the best script for 
understanding, maintainable, effective and simple (may not).

Please don't say what are all you know. Please tell me the best

Comment: Hi Mohanavel, you may get downvoted for this question because it is very high-level / subjective / might require extended debate / discussion.  Most would probably recommend that you jump in and start coding.  For example, try using Python.  Most would agree that Python is highly understandable, maintainable, effective, simple, and elegant even.

Comment: Most *Python users* would agree that - and that is of course the problem with questions like this: people tend to like what they know.

Comment: Thanks for guidance. I'll explore two/three and i'll find the right script for right place

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are **no bests**. It is possible in all the scripting languages ([Perl](http://perl.org/), [Python](http://www.python.org/), [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/)). Check the documentation at the respective sites and select for yourself the one that suits your way of thinking/coding.

Comment: "no bests".. apart from PHP! R0X0RZ!

Comment: @Assembler epic fail for using l337speak, but +1 for making me roflcoptor!

Answer (score 4):

Mohanavel, the question as it stands can not be answered until you define what you mean by "best".

That aside, when it comes to programming languages... Just *pick* one, learn it, find out what's crap in it, then move onto another language.  As a programmer you need to learn many languages anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has the most simple syntax and with Ruby On Rails (which is a framework) you can get a web application working in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You'll never find a consensus as to which language is best, ever, until the end of time. That being said, Python seems like a good fit for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I dispute that...  When the end of time finally comes around, we STILL won't have a consensus! We may, however, have a consensus once hell has frozen over, though...

Answer (score 0):

Use [**python**](http://python.org) for your web applications ([**Django**](http://djangoproject.com) framework will do the trick for your)

Then for socket programming use **Python** again ([**Twisted**](http://twistedmatrix.com) python package will be the library to use for networking functionality)

Best of luck

Comment: Why this answer is down voted. Answering will give clear idea.